# How to download streamed files with wget?

Tags: linux, download, wget

Sometimes I stumble in files I cannot download with `wget`. So maybe someone has a hint for me?

For example I want to download via the following link:
https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=2516&cf_id=24

So I type:

```
wget https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=2516&cf_id=24
```

`wget` does create a file with the name `attachment.php?link_id=2516&cf_id=24` and it's unfortunately empty.

I've also tested it with options like `--trust-server-names`, but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` needs to be escaped, because it put the foreground task into the background.

So the following works:

```
wget https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=2516\&cf_id=24
```